Static server side rendering of Routes component in Blazor
If render mode isn't set in the "Routes" component, theoretically it should render as static server side as same as the "App" component,
what does that mean?
what's its effect on other interactive components that render mode has been set explicitly? will it have a downside on them?
Is it a good choice not to specify render mode for routes?

No, this is question that I came across it during a project


If render mode isn't set in the "Routes" component, theoretically it should render as static server side as same as the "App" component, what does that mean?

This means if you don't set any render mode in the "Routes" component like this:<Routes /> inside the blazor app, it will use the same rendering approach as the parent component (like the "App" component in this case).
In short, the app controls the render mode globally by setting the render mode on the Routes component.
If you don't have set the route, the default value for the route is Static server-side rendering (static SSR).

what's its effect on other interactive components that render mode has been set explicitly? will it have a downside on them?

When you set the render mode inside the other conponent, it will override the default value. So, even the default value is SSR , these components will behave as defined in their render-mode.

Is it a good choice not to specify render mode for routes?

It depends on your apps design, if you want all your app is Interactive Server  , you just need set once.

Thanks for your answer, my question was more conceptual, when the route component executes static SSR, while the route is not a kind of output component, then what behind the scenes is being done?
Routing will happen in the server but will WASM components render in the browser?
I'm React developer as well, in React the whole app is either server side or client side (usually) but in the new Blazor, there is a chance to set it by each component. But Route component is not clear the concept behind static SSR?

I tested setting the <Route @rendermode="InteractiveServer" /> while route was located in server project, then in the client project set the render mode of a page to WASM, but get "Not found". I expected that the client would rewrite the render mode attribute of Route component. but it did not
